# How to print a one to many linq query to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have this as my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid UserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        using (var db = new MatchGamingEntities())
        {
            var MyAccount = from m in db.Accounts
                            join n in db.BankTransactions on m.AccountId equals n.AccountId
                            where m.UserId == UserId
                            select new{Accounts = m, BankTransaction = n};

            return View(MyAccount.SingleOrDefault());
        }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@model MatchGaming.Models.BankStatement
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Bank Statement</h2>
<a href="/Cashier/Withdrawal">Withdrawal</a> | <a href="/Cashier/Deposit">Deposit</a><br /><br />
<fieldset>
    <legend>BankStatement</legend>
     <p>
        Balance: @Model.Balance
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the BankStatement Model

```
public class BankStatement
{
    public decimal Balance;

}
```

Currently my table "BankTransactions" could have multiple records in there with the same Account Id, so when I run this query I get a more than one bank transaction related to a given accountid. I want to be able to print this into a view, but I am not sure how my `var MyAccount` is returning given that there are multiple BankTransactions.

How would I transfer this model into the view and be able to iterate through all the bank transactions associated with an AccountId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model in your control and in your view dose not match.

you need assign value to your model `BankStatement` first, than return it to your view.

some thing like

```
BankStatement statement = new BankStatement();
//boxing value to statement
return View(statement);
```